# Нужна помощь с mod_rewrite

Tags: mod_rewrite

Доброго времени суток, коллеги. Появилась такая задача: заказчик арендует выделенный сервер, есть основной домен domain.com, нужно чтобы поддомены user1.domain.com, user2.domain.com попадали на domain.com/user1/ и domain.com/user2/ соответственно. При этом все это дело должно происходить динамический - зарегистрировался новый пользователь и получился поддомен. Думаю что это можно сделать с помощью mod_rewrite, но что-то пока не могу осилить. Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Попробуйте так:  

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.site\.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.site\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/subdomain/%1/$1 [L,P]
Чтобы это работало нужен mod_proxy. Если же убрать флаг Р, то будет происходить внешний редирект, что не красиво в данном случае.  
Убрать папку subdomain нельзя, иначе будет циклическая переадресация.  

А вообще же использовать mod_rewrite для динамических доменов третьего уровня можно, но это не правильно.

Answer (score 1):

вот ваше решение http://habrahabr.ru/post/101585/
...от сердца отрываю :)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, Вам нужно смотреть в сторону редиректов с www.site.com на site.com в .htaccess и по аналогии подредактировать регулярку под Вашу ситуацию .
Вот [link](http://seodiz.ru/htaccess-redirekt-s-www-i-bez-www-301)